# Formula to Arrange table by performance

Tags: statistics

I have the following table where I need to arrange persons based on performance. By performance, I mean the person with the **highest [Total] with most [Correct].**

From looking at the table:

1. Sly is the person with the most [Total] and having the most
   [Correct] items.
2. Jimmy, despite being top of the table actually
   has too many [Incorrect]
3. I cannot arrange by [ERR%] in ascending
   order because then people with very few [Total] will rise to the
   top. The criteria is that they must have plenty of [Total] as well.

**Is there any formula I can apply to make Sly top of the table?**

Thanks.

```
Name    |   [Total] [Correct]   [InCorrect] [Error%]
----------------------------------------------------
Jimmy   |   42        12         30          71.4%
Sly     |   36        31         5           13.9%
Janet   |   10         7         3           30.0%
Ebony   |   7          7         0           0.0%
Chloe   |   5          5         0           0.0%
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, $Total \cdot (100-Error)$ will give you who solved the most problems correctly. Or you can simply sort by $Correct$.

Comment: Sorting by [CORRECT] in descending order is the closest to what I was looking. However Ebony was placed above Janet who has more [Total]. Thanks for your help! I think this should do.